# Blazor KeyDown event not working on Android

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Given the following Blazor Component as a minimal reproducible example:

```
<p>@Text</p>
<input @onkeydown="RefreshText"/>

@code {
    private string Text = "";

    private void RefreshText(KeyboardEventArgs eventData)
    {
        Text = eventData.Code;
    }
}
```

I expect the input field to refresh the paragraph with a new key code on each keydown event.

This example works as expected on PC, but when I run it on an Android mobile device, the paragraph is always empty.

What's the reason for that and how to make it work on Android?

Here is a fiddle with the presented example: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/pdv6eqw4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I decided to go with [Blazor custom events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-event-arguments).

Event definition:

```
[EventHandler("oncustomkeydown", typeof(CustomKeyDownEventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers { }

public class CustomKeyDownEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Key { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Event registration with [Blazor JS initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-initializers):

```
export function afterStarted(blazor) {
    blazor.registerCustomEventType('customkeydown', {
        browserEventName: 'keydown',
        createEventArgs: event => {
            return {
                key: event.key,
                code: event.code
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
<p>@Text</p>
<input @oncustomkeydown="RefreshText"/>

@code {
    private string Text = "";

    private void RefreshText(CustomKeyDownEventArgs eventData)
    {
        Text = eventData.Code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried @oninput instead of @onKeyDown?

If you tried @oninput, it will execute whatever you are passing into the input box on every key press.

Try that and see if that fixed your issue.

Comment: Yes, @oninput works as expected on all platforms. It is a good workaround for some cases, but unfortunately not all since it does not cover special keys, enter key etc.